# MariaDB NodeJS backend : too many connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb

I have a NodeJS express backend which uses a MariaDB database.

My file dbconnect.js creates a mariadb pool and has a function to make queries.

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const pool = mariadb.createPool({ 
  host: process.env.DBHost, 
  user: process.env.DBUser, 
  database: process.env.DB, 
  password: process.env.DBSecret 
});

const dbQuery = async(query) => {
    let conn;
    let res = '';
    try {
        conn = await pool.getConnection();
        res = await conn.query(query);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error sending Query: ", query, err.text);
    } finally {
        if (conn) {
            conn.end();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work perfectly, but after a few months with the server running these messages begin to appear on the console:

[image: Data base error too many connections]

These messages keep appearing every 10-14 seconds, but no queries are being performed.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but `conn.end()` does return a Promise so perhaps `await conn.end()` would be a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but there is one way,

configure your connection pool to ping at particular time. so it will close any inactive connections before the server closes them.  `mariadb` has `pingInterval` for this

Replace this code with your code

```js
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
  host: process.env.DBHost,
  user: process.env.DBUser,
  database: process.env.DB,
  password: process.env.DBSecret,
  pingInterval: 60000
});
```

This will send a ping to the server every `60 seconds`, which will prevent the server from closing inactive connections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mandeep , but what is the explanation? Why does my Database keep opened the connections?

Comment: There are many Reasons:

Connection pooling, Idle connections, Long-running queries, Insufficient max_connections, Insufficient wait_timeout

You can check how many connections are currently open by using this command
SHOW PROCESSLIST;

For more detail. Please check the documentation

I hope you like my answer